# Moodle rebase to another stable version - merge conflicts

Tags: git, upgrade, moodle, rebase

Trying to upgrade my moodle clone to another stable version and bring my modifications along. I've got development branch with all my modifications (no modifications to core files) branched out of one stable version that I tried to rebase onto another stable version. The problem is that (from what i've read) the way moodle is developed\maintained different branches\versions deviate a lot from each other over the time, and when trying to rebase even clean custom branch from one stable version onto another I get about 200 merge conflicts. Any ideas, solutions?

Answer (score 0):

I'd recommend using Tim Hunt's method, as detailed here:
https://moodle.org/mod/forum/discuss.php?d=191774#p834646

Basically, you create a branch based on the latest code, which has all the commits, but none of the code from the Moodle branch your code is based on. At that point, you can merge in your custom branch and it gets your custom commits, but ignores any commits that are part of the standard Moodle code.

Copied from the above link:

```
git checkout -b merge_helper_branch MOODLE_22_STABLE
git merge --strategy=ours MOODLE_21_STABLE
git checkout my_customisations
git merge --strategy-option=patience merge_helper_branch
```